# Getting error on facebook connect's all.js line 64 "Unexpected token }"

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to integrate facebook connect onto my website using my local test server, and for some reason, I can't even get past including all.js script in the page while trying to follow this tutorial:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

I have this:
`<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>`

Which throws (Chrome 12):
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }       all.js:64`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have some Javascript above that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's facebook having issues with their javascript, 10 minutes after asking this question, the problem's gone by itself :S